# Calling JavaScript alert from a static method in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, static-methods

How to call a JavaScript `alert` from a static method in C#?

I have tried the following code but the method does not get called.

```
 public static void WriteToErrorLog()
 {   
     Page mypage = new Page();
     ErrorMessage(mypage);                
 }
 public static void ErrorMessage(Page page)
 {
     page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "alert", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Oops something went wrong, please try later...!!');</script>");
 }
```

Comment: What server tech are you using? ASP.Net/MVC?

Comment: Have you tried `Response.Write("<script>alert('Oops something went wrong, please try later...!!');</script>");`

Comment: You're registering the script on a local instance of `Page` that disappears when it goes out of scope..

Comment: .. and what's this got to do with jQuery? Did you mean Javascript?

Comment: I am using Asp.net

Comment: The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context..

Comment: its for javascript alert..

Comment: A static method has no concept of the context (HTTP request) that is being run. Basically *don't use a static method*. Put code (not necessarily that code) in a basecontroller and inherit all controllers from that controller.

Comment: Why don't you just not make it static?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Jquery function from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216177/how-to-call-jquery-function-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code to get a reference to the current ScriptManager:

```
var currentScriptManager = System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);
```

and then use it as per the following example:

```
currentScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "pagename", " ", "alert('ERROR')", true);
```

Comment: You can't use `this` in a static method

Comment: @stuartd: indeed you can, he is already passing reference to the page.

Comment: @stuartd: and if he is not passing the page, he can get a reference to is by using the following line `(Page)(HttpContext.Current.Handler)`

Comment: [Why keyword 'this' cannot be used in a static method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459282/why-keyword-this-cannot-be-used-in-a-static-method)

Comment: @stuartd: thanks for the link: I've updated the code to the the page parameter instead of the `this` keyword.

Comment: you missed `this.GetType()` :)

Comment: @stuartd: if you see something wrong you are more than welcomed to modify the answer, we should do this as this is the sole idea behind SO, help each other not drawing smilies (you should always appreciate the effort, not blame typos and missing parts). anyway appreciate your comments.

Comment: thanks @Mohammed, (Page)(HttpContext.Current.Handler) its working..